# Tunnel Web API video stream response through MVC action

Tags: asp.net-mvc, api, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-web-api2

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/820146/HTTP-Partial-Content-In-ASP-NET-Web-API-Video

Using the link above I created a web api call that will return a video and play with no issues if I call the web api directly.  In production the web api call will be behind a firewall and not directly accessible to the public.  And for reasons that are way too long I cannot add a web api service to the public facing website.

I would like to tunnel the call to a video through a MVC action and return the exact result from the web api controller to the user.  Web api returns a HttpResponseMessage so I used the code below thinking I can just tunnel the respose through but it doesn't seem to be working at all.

```
public HttpResponseMessage Play(string fileName)
{
    using (var client = new HttpClient())
    {
        var userName = Impersonation.Instance.CurrentImpersonatedUser;
        var url = string.Format("{0}/api/Player/Play?f={1}",
                                                this.pluginSettings["VirtualVideoTrainingServiceURL"],
                                                fileName);
        var result = client.GetAsync(url).Result;
        return result;
    }
}
```

When I make to the call to the MVC action I just get this in the browser.
[Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/huHN9.png)
I think it's serializing the data in some way but I am unable to prove or disprove that theory.  Do I need to parse the response from the web service and then convert it to a file result?  Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I found the answer.

http://www.dotnetcurry.com/aspnet-mvc/998/play-videos-aspnet-mvc-custom-action-filter

Warning: code below needs to be cleaned up.

Using this as an example I created an ActionResult called VideoResult that looks like

```
private byte[] Buffer = null;
private string FileName = string.Empty;
private ContentRangeHeaderValue Range = null;
private string Length = string.Empty;

public VideoResult(byte[] buffer, string fileName, ContentRangeHeaderValue range, string length)
{
     this.Buffer = buffer;
     this.FileName = fileName;
     this.Range = range;
     this.Length = length;
}

/// <summary>
/// The below method will respond with the Video file
/// </summary>
/// <param name="context"></param>
public override void ExecuteResult(ControllerContext context)
{
     //The header information
     context.HttpContext.Response.StatusCode = (int)HttpStatusCode.PartialContent;
     if (this.Range != null)
     {
          context.HttpContext.Response.AddHeader("Content-Range", string.Format("bytes {0}-{1}/{2}", this.Range.From, this.Range.To, this.Range.Length));
     }
     context.HttpContext.Response.AddHeader("Content-Type", "video/mp4");
     context.HttpContext.Response.AddHeader("Content-Length", this.Length);
     context.HttpContext.Response.BinaryWrite(Buffer);
}
```

I retrieve the byte array from the Content as a ByteArray from the StreamContent (or PushStreamContent) and pass that data into the VideoResult above.

```
    var sc = ((StreamContent)result.Content).ReadAsByteArrayAsync();
    return new VideoResult(sc.Result, fileName, result.Content.Headers.ContentRange, 
result.Content.Headers.ContentLength.ToString());
```

This also allows the user to seek the video.  I was hoping to just pass the result from the Web service directly through, but as shown above the responses are just too different and thusly will need to be converted to a MVC Action result.

Answer (score 0):

WebAPI Handler composes the response into headers, content and other parameters and that will be sent to the user based on Http specification and content negotiation with the client/consumer of the service.

On the other hand, you can just get JSON content from the service and pass it through the MVC Action.

You can get the content returned in the `HttpResponseMessage` using `object<HttpResponseMessage>.Content`

MVC makes use of `IActionResult`(used by `System.Web.Mvc.Controller`) to compose the result of action method executed, WebAPI's `System.Web.Http.ApiController` uses `IHttpActionResult` to compose the output.

Comment: For a normal model you are correct, but this will be returning a piped stream of a file so I need avoid JSON.  The MVC action will used in the src attribute of a video html element.

Comment: Why not add a Controller that derives from ApiController and the pipe the output to your clients? @RodneyPannell

Comment: Hard to explain as why I cannot add WebAPI controller to the public site, but ApiController cannot be used on the public facing site.  It's not a "normal" MVC site.  We normally using RestSharp to contact web api behind the file wall, but this is a complete different scenario than pulling a model from a database.